# Is iAd Suite (tabbed banner) buggy?

Tags: iphone, ios

After implementing iAds in my app using the Apple example of the tabbed banner. I noticed that I am getting the "banner has an add but may be obscured warning". So because of my relative noobish status i tried to find my mistake. After much searching I couldn't find an answer, and in desperation, i ran the Apple sample code on its own in the simulator, and it too gives the "banner may be obscured warning". Am I missing something. Is this a bug?

Comment: Pity the answers went astray on this one...its a perfectly valid question to ask, why does Apple published code contain this warning?...Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

I think iAd gives you the "may be obscured" warning if the iAd is not the frontmost view in the current view hierarchy.  I haven't thoroughly tested this assertion though.

If you are using Interface Builder you can bring the iAd to the front by moving it lower down on the list of objects on your view controller.  In code you would add the Banner Ad last.

Edit: nix this theory - the message reappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Means banner has a part which is not fully or partly visible.

Search google or stackoverflow there is plenty answers on this question

Comment: @jrturton , This is first question of this user !!! ,  i told him why this error occur  , and i also saw plenty of questions on this issue over time , i don't have all the time anybody know how to search

Comment: I agree, i could have been clearer. I have checked, and the ad is fully visible, and if you read the rest of my question.. It also happens with APPLES CODE,untouched, and unmolested.. and i was asking if anyone knew if it was a bug, as i want to use these methods in my app.. but can't. I refer to the "newest" version.              Version 2.0, 2011-10-31
Updated for iOS 5.0, removed support for iOS 4.1 and below, added samples that use a custom container view controller to manage the ADBannerView, converted all samples to use ARC.